# $.getjson not working / json storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to do a getJSON call to a page within my domain that is simply a json array, which is not returning anything given the script in my webpage:

```
<script>
      $('#genButton').click(function() {
        console.log("click");
        $.getJSON("http://mygithub.github.io/repository/quotedb.json", function(data){
          console.log("executing");
          var entry = data[Math.floor(Math.random()*data.length)];
          console.log(entry);
          $("#quoteDisplay").text(entry);
        }).fail(function() { 
          console.log( "error" ); 
        });
      })
</script>
```

When the button is clicked, the console logs the "click", but never logs "executing", but also doesn't log any errors related to the getJSON. The debugger also never pauses within the getJSON function.

My question is, 1. Is it valid for quotedb.json to be literally a webpage with just a single json array? Or does the page need to be annotated in some way so that the getJSON request knows where to pick up the json from? 2. If (1) is fine, then are there any other reasons you can see why nothing from the getJSON return function would appear?

The json is again one array of json objects, in the form:

```
{
  "character": ""
  "quote": ""
}
```

**EDITS**

With the edited code, it now outputs "click" followed by "error" from the .fail() method of the $.getJSON call now.

I tried removing the ?callback? section of the url as suggested below, which did not work.

The `/repository/` section of my url seems to be necessary to access the file.

Comment: What is the response to the request in the network tab of your javascript console?

Comment: Handle the errors, not just the success. The answer could be there.

Comment: @bhspencer, thank you!! I didn't realize there was a network tab, but that helped me figure out that the request was ok, but that the json was slightly misformatted and being read in as a bunch of badly formed objects. It all worked once I fixed the json array

Answer (score 2):

Try without `?callback=?` at end of `url`, see [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

> **JSONP**
>
> If the URL includes the string `"callback=?"` (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the
>   discussion of the `jsonp` data type in `$.ajax()` for more details.

Comment: The answer provided by @guest271314 should fix the problem.  When I tested this with my own GitHub pages site, with the JSON file in the root, I did not require the `/repository/` part of the url as @rzs presented it.  You should be able to verify the proper serving of the JSON file just by hitting the proper url in the browser, either: `http://mygithub.github.io/repository/quotedb.json` or possibly `http://mygithub.github.io/quotedb.json`